# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when i trying to write message to file

Tags: java

I'm a starting Java developer. I want to write e-mail client with GUI, but I have a problem when I try to run `WriteMessages` thread. I'm using JavaMail library.

```
public class WriteMessages implements Runnable {

    private List<Message> list;
    private Properties properties;
    private Utilities util = new Utilities();

    public WriteMessages(List<Message> list, Properties properties) {
        this.list = list;
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Iterator<Message> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            Message m = iter.next(); //line 42 exception occurs there

            String name = Morda.produceFileName(m);

            File file = new File(properties.getProperty("PathToMessages") + "//" + name);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }

            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);){
                m.writeTo(os);
                System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " was wrote succesfuly");
            } catch (IOException | MessagingException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Message 0 added successfully.
Message 1 added successfully.
Message 2 added successfully.
Message 3 added successfully.
Thread is interrupted.
File 2011_07_17_08_55_27.mes was wrote succesfuly
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:886)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:836)
    at util.WriteMessages.run(WriteMessages.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But, when I remove this snippet of code:

```
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);){
    m.writeTo(os);
    System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " was wrote succesfuly");
} catch (IOException | MessagingException ex) {
}
```

The exception doesn't appear. I think that this problem was already solved, but I can't find how. Please help me to fix this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Solved. Thanks all for help. I used advice by @TagirValeev and simply replace `ArrayList` by `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and all is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In concurrent environment consider using [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of simple `ArrayList`. When you start iterating it, you will iterate a content of the list which was at the time of iteration start. Usually that's desired behavior. Using `Collections.synchronizedList` will not actually help preventing `ConcurrentModificationException` and may make your application less responsive.

Comment: **Thanks**. It help me to solve this problem. **Thank**.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect another thread is accessing the list while this thread is iterating over the messages in the list. This is because the list reference is shared and passed to the thread in its constructor.

Try synchronizing on the list object whenever it is used in this or other threads. You can use a synchronized list:

```
List<Message> messageList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
```

After this you'd still have to synchronize when iterating over the list (and this is actually the most important thing to do here to avoid the `ConcurrentModificationException`):

```
synchronized(messageList) {
    Iterator<Message> iter = messageList.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve it by synchronizing the access of the method from which this thread is spawned.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be caused that you modify the list with messages in other thread and as the ArrayList is not thread-safe you should consider another List implementation that would be.
Regarding thread-safe implementations you can read more [at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397154/4907382)